# Spaces in command line argument not working

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments, filepath

I have requirement to execute the command line arguments. If file path contains the Spaces it doesn’t work properly. It returns the error file not found. The program is given below.

```
public void Method()
{
    string docFile = @"C:\Test Document1.doc";
    string docxFile = @"C:\Test Document1.docx";
    string file = @"C:\doc2x_r649 (1)\doc2x_r649\doc2x.exe";

    ExecuteCommand(file, string.Format(docFile + " -o " + docxFile));
}

public static string ExecuteCommand(string file, string command)
{
    String result;
    try
    {
        //Create a new ProcessStartInfo
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        //Settings
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.FileName = file;
        procStartInfo.Arguments = command;
        //Create new Process
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        //Set ProcessStartInfo
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        //Start Process
        proc.Start();
        //Wait to exit
        proc.WaitForExit();
        //Get Result
        result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        //Return
        return result;
    }
    catch
    {

    }

    return null;
}
```

If file path doesn't contains spaces it works properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding quotes to your paths?

```
ExecuteCommand(file, string.Format("\"" + docFile + "\" -o \"" + docxFile + "\""));
```

Comment: Why do you use `string.Format` if all you do is string concatination

Comment: @I4V: I used the original code posted in the question, but you're right, there's no need of `string.Format` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
ExecuteCommand(file, string.Format("\"{0}\" -o \"{1}\"",docFile , docxFile));
```